# AEM 6.2- MongoDB: MSRP search results between given time range

Tags: mongodb-query, aem

I am trying to search for MSRP resources between given time range. I am trying to use below timeConstraint. (Made sure there are entries between that time range)

```
final Constraint timeConstraint = new RangeConstraint<Long>("timestamp_tl", until, cal.getTimeInMillis(), true);
```

"until" above is time in millis less than cal.getTimeInMillis(). Adding above timeConstraint to:

```
final ConstraintGroup mainConstraintGroup = new ConstraintGroup(Operator.And);
```

I added entries to MongoDB with additional property "timestamp_tl". Earlier I tried with just "timestamp".

In both cases I am getting error -

```
07.04.2017 17:08:00.100 *ERROR* [sling-default-4727-com.mycomp.proj.core.services.Mysearch.12850] com.mycomp.proj.core.services.MySearchTest Task failed!
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Decimal searches not supported yet
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.getValueStringSolr(LuceneQueryFactory.java:554)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.getValueString(LuceneQueryFactory.java:542)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.getPropertyValueQuery(LuceneQueryFactory.java:511)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.getComparisonQuery(LuceneQueryFactory.java:487)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.mapConstraintToQueryAndFilter(LuceneQueryFactory.java:316)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.mapConstraintToQueryAndFilter(LuceneQueryFactory.java:281)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.mapConstraintToQueryAndFilter(LuceneQueryFactory.java:282)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.LuceneQueryFactory.getStatement(LuceneQueryFactory.java:164)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.QueryObjectModelImpl.getSelectorStatement(QueryObjectModelImpl.java:168)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.sc.lucene.QueryObjectModelImpl.getStatement(QueryObjectModelImpl.java:109)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.ugc.impl.LuceneUgcSearch.findCloudResources(LuceneUgcSearch.java:959)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.ugc.impl.LuceneUgcSearch.find(LuceneUgcSearch.java:805)
        at com.adobe.cq.social.ugc.impl.LuceneUgcSearch.find(LuceneUgcSearch.java:719)
        at org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzJobExecutor.execute(QuartzJobExecutor.java:118)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that I need to use

```
final Constraint timeConstraint = new RangeConstraint<Date>("timestamp", until, cal.getTime(), true);
```

Above 'until' and 'cal.getTime()' are java.util.Date objects. I was assuming the "timestamp" value saved in MongoDB is "long" value since it was displaying as `"NumberLong("1492006094509")"`